# Wiring 2 double 3 switches

Tags: electrical

I have two double 3-way switches one upstairs and one downstairs. The bottom toggle on both switch controls the living room and the top toggle controls the top upstairs hall light.  The problem is that for the downstairs light (the only one I hooked up as of now) is that the top switch must be on for the light to be on. I connected the 12/3 wiring to what I think it should be hooked up to, namely A1 (traveler) going to A1 on switch 2 and B1 (line) going to B1 on switch 2.   Obviously I want 3 way switching behavior but the product diagram doesn't include a diagram for double 3 way to double 3 way switch connections.   Can anybody  help so I can work on the other light??

Switch2 (going to light)
[image]

[image: the cable from switch1]
[image: switch2][image: going out to the light]
[image: Bad hand drawn diagram]

Comment: Nice job with your sketch. It is totally unreadable being as you chose to have it upside down,

Comment: Just the way the photo upload - but you figured out that it is upside down so plus points for your problem solving.  So know that you recognize that it is upside what do you think genius?

Comment: By "top switch", which of the four switches in this setup do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### All mixed up

Your single set of travelers has been split between the two switches in the dual switch set.  In order to unconfuse things, I'd move the wire from the A1 terminal to the B2 terminal on each switch in your diagram.

P.S. there are two travellers between a pair of 3-way switches, not a traveller and a "hot".

Comment: Thanks a lot that is what I thought initially but then I looked at the mfr diagram and got mixed up and tried to follow it but when you said about the traveler in pair the diagram made more sense too.  Thanks again.